# How to exclude "\n" escape character from trim() method?

Tags: java, trim

Given a text, it contains information rows as new lines. I need to perform something like a custom parsing to split these rows and save them into an array. Since the new lines in the text are determined by the escape character "\n", i'm performing the parsing according to these escape characters. The problem is, some text data comes with a lot of whitespaces outside the main data text. And when i proceed to perform another split operation to turn the rows into key, value pairs, these whitespaces causing me problems during runtime.

Is there a way in Java so i can trim a String but exclude "\n" escape character ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the input text looks like and what the output would be. Can you please edit your question to include a relevant sample of this text and the output you expect? There's no way to exclude characters from `trim`, but an alternate solution may be possible knowing the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Please add kind of example what have you done/tried and what is needed.

Comment: Why don't you split on `\n`, trim and then add `\n` to each row afterwards? When splitting on new line char  like `text.split("\n")` this sequence gets lost anyway and must be put back afterwards. I would anyway rather suggest to split on `\\R` which is Java's new version of detecting new lines: `text.split("\\R")`

Comment: and add the second argument as in `text.split("\n", -1)` (to @Slevin suggestion) if you want to preserve all `\n` (including the ones on the end of the text)

Comment: I would  also test `text.stripIndent().indent(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` (but not sure if I did understand the question correctly)

Answer (score 3):

If you’re reading from a file, don’t read the entire file content into a single string.  Instead, trim each line:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(
        Path.of("C:\\Users\\caliskanata\\Documents\\file.txt"))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line.trim());
    }
}
```

If your text is not coming from a file, you can split it as Slevin suggested, and trim each part:

```
String[] untrimmedLines = text.split("\\R");
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(untrimmedLines.length);
for (String untrimmedLine : untrimmedLines) {
    lines.add(untrimmedLine.trim());
}
```

You can also do it with a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream(java.lang.CharSequence)):

```
List<String> lines =
    Pattern.compile("\\R").splitAsStream(text).map(String::trim).toList();
```

Since you wrote “save them into an array,” you can easily convert a List to an array:

```
String[] array = lines.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: but be aware that using the one-argument `split()` will discard all newlines at the end of the text (maybe even desired?)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it manually, but it is not that hard. If you already split your string into multiple strings based on `\n` character than all your string will only have character `\n` only once or not at all, and if your String has `\n` character it will always will be the last one. So, what you can do is

```
boolean newLinePresent = myString.endsWith("\n");
myString = myString.trim();
if(newLinePresent) {
  myString = myString + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that `trim` returns a NEW string, it doesn't modify the string! You have to assign the return value to something.

Comment: Yes, modified the code, thanks for catching, but that doesn't take away from clarity of the answer